# Sending a Post request multipart/form-data

Tags: php, http-headers

I've encountered problem trying to send a Post request and get result, here is my code:

```
function connect2($hostname,$method,$path,$data,$cookie){
$fp=fsockopen($hostname, 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
    if(!$fp) echo "$errstr($errno)<br>/>\n";
    else{
        $headers="$method $path HTTP/1.1\r\n";
        $headers.= "Host: $hostname\r\n";
        if($cookie) $headers.="Cookie: $cookie\r\n";
        if($method=="POST") $headers.="Content-length: ".strlen($data)."\r\n";
        if($method=="POST") $headers.="Content-Type: multipart/form-data;  boundary=---------------------------4358114262792\r\n";
        $headers.="Referer: http://ospb.dev.1adw.com/vt/houses/add\r\n";
        $headers.="Connection: keep-alive\r\n";
        if($method=="POST")$headers.="\r\n\$data\r\n";
        $headers.="\r\n";
        fwrite($fp, $headers);
        $line="";
        while(!feof($fp)){
            $line.=fgets($fp, 1024);
        }
        fclose($fp);
    }
    return $line ;

}
$data="-----------------------------4358114262792\r\n"
."Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"action\"\r\n\r\n".
"add\r\n".
"-----------------------------4358114262792\r\n".
"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"selectedTab\"\r\n\r\n".
"0\r\n".
"-----------------------------4358114262792\r\n".
"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"house[officeId]\"\r\n\r\n".
"450\r\n".
"-----------------------------4358114262792\r\n".
"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"house[streetId]\"\r\n\r\n".
"968432\r\n".
"-----------------------------4358114262792\r\n".
"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"house[number]\"\r\n\r\n".
"20\r\n".
"-----------------------------4358114262792\r\n".
"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"house[building]\"\r\n\r\n".
"1\r\n".
"-----------------------------4358114262792\r\n".
"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"house[sourceUrl]\"\r\n\r\n".
"http://uk-sozidanie.ru/homes/\r\n".
"-----------------------------4358114262792\r\n".
"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"house[statusId]\"\r\n\r\n".
"1\r\n".
"-----------------------------4358114262792\r\n".
"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"__token\"\r\n\r\n".
"cfc3901629435\r\n".
"-----------------------------4358114262792--";
...
$b = connect2("ospb.dev.1adw.com", "POST", "/vt/houses/add", $data ,$cookie);
```

And here is the error:

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\cdo\www\add.php on line 46
```

I'm just trying to simulate a real request that works fine and returns good result almost imidietly.

Added:
Did I count my data length properly?

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your file, after the `<?php` tag, put `set_time_limit(0);` for unlimited processing time... or use something higher, like `120`

Comment: this request shouldn't last longer than 30 seconds, but I tried 120 seconds and it doesn't return anything. Just no response: no response headers, nothing

Comment: You'll need to debug your request then.

Answer (score 0):

You should use cURL functions in PHP for all HTTP/HTTP requests, that should solve your problem.

If you dont want to use cURL, pls post actual request/response headers from actual request that you are sending. Problem could be with the $vars data you are sending in it.